# Как сделать так, чтобы автоматически не перебрасывало на страницу, указанную в header на подключаемой странице php

Tags: php

Нужна помощь.У меня есть файл, назовем его index.php.В нем есть подключение файла inc.php.В inc.php есть в условии header, примерно так:

```
if(условие){
header:...
}else{
header:...
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы перебрасывало только на подлючаемом файле(inc.php), но не на основном(index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/inc.php')  { 
       //header
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!